# CRM 2011: Custom Workflow Activity Output Parameters don´t show

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, output, workflow-activity

everyone,
I'm having a problem that does not appear in the output parameter list on the right side under "Look for" underneath "Local Values", I do not understand the problem or reason for not appear, since in terms of input parameters's okay.

```cs
protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

            //Create the context
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            tracingService.Trace("Creating Account");

            Account entity = new Account();
            entity.Name = AccountName.Get<string>(executionContext);
            Guid entityId = service.Create(entity);

            string a = entity.Name;

            AccountNameTest.Set(executionContext, a);

            tracingService.Trace("Account created with Id {0}", entityId.ToString());

            tracingService.Trace("Create a task for the account");
            Task newTask = new Task();
            newTask.Subject = TaskSubject.Get<string>(executionContext);
            newTask.RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, entityId);

            Guid taskId = service.Create(newTask);

            tracingService.Trace("Task has been created");

            tracingService.Trace("Retrieve the task using QueryByAttribute");
            QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute();
            query.Attributes.AddRange(new string[] { "regardingobjectid" });
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "subject" });
            query.EntityName = Task.EntityLogicalName;
            query.Values.AddRange(new object[] { entityId });

            tracingService.Trace("Executing the Query for entity {0}", query.EntityName);

            //Execute using a request to test the OOB (XRM) message contracts
            RetrieveMultipleRequest request = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
            request.Query = query;
            Collection<Entity> entityList = ((RetrieveMultipleResponse)service.Execute(request)).EntityCollection.Entities;

            //Execute a request from the CRM message assembly
            tracingService.Trace("Executing a WhoAmIRequest");
            service.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());

            if (1 != entityList.Count)
            {
                tracingService.Trace("The entity list was too long");
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Query did not execute correctly");
            }
            else
            {
                tracingService.Trace("Casting the Task from RetrieveMultiple to strong type");
                Task retrievedTask = (Task)entityList[0];

                if (retrievedTask.ActivityId != taskId)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Incorrect task was retrieved");
                }

                tracingService.Trace("Retrieving the entity from IOrganizationService");

                //Retrieve the task using Retrieve
                retrievedTask = (Task)service.Retrieve(Task.EntityLogicalName, retrievedTask.Id, new ColumnSet("subject"));
                if (!string.Equals(newTask.Subject, retrievedTask.Subject, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Task's subject did not get retrieved correctly");
                }

                //Update the task
                retrievedTask.Subject = UpdatedTaskSubject.Get<string>(executionContext);
                service.Update(retrievedTask);
            }
        }
        //
        [Input("Name conta")]
        [Default("testv01")]
        public InArgument<string> AccountName { get; set; }

        [Input("Task")]
        [Default("testv01")]
        public InArgument<string> TaskSubject { get; set; }

        [Input("Update task")]
        [Default("testUPDATED:v01}")]
        public InArgument<string> UpdatedTaskSubject { get; set; }

        [Output("Account ID Guid")]
        [Default("testUPDATED:v01")]
        public OutArgument<string> AccountNameTest { get; set; }
```

Comment: which type is the target field you want to apply the output argument? because your output type is string the name "AccountNameTest" will not be displayed when you focus a different type field (for example a lookup)

Comment: @Guido Preite, please can you tell how i do it?

Comment: the output argument will be visible in the steps after your custom activity, if for example you create an email you can put your output argument inside subject or description because are string fields, but not inside regarding or bcc fields because they are lookups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved, just restart IIS to assume the fields, or through version change. The problem was the update of the plugin, this also happens with workflows. According to CRM 4.0 i realized this situation does not happen in CRM 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this Question is already answered I wanted to share two Cases where this solution didn't work (even in a recent Version of CRM):

### Case 1

Having choosen Input-Parameter-Names that contained german Umlauts (äöüß).

IIS-restart did not help.
Choosing Names without Umlauts solved the Problem for me.

### Case 2

We recently also had a case where a normal In-Argument did not show up, even after restarting the entire Maschine CRM was running on. The Solution was not to obvious:

1. Open PluginRegistrationTool from SDK
2. Choose the Assembly that contains your CWA
3. Choose your CWA
4. Hit the Save-Button in the Properties-Tab of your CWA