# Usage of <string> in method call before parameters

Tags: c#

I found this code at [CRM 2011: Custom Workflow Activity Output Parameters don´t show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011966/crm-2011-custom-workflow-activity-output-parameters-dont-show) and wonder what `<string>` does here

```
entity.Name = AccountName.Get<string>(executionContext);
```

Comment: IMO This is not a _good way_ to ask a question on Stackoverflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: `ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical`? `cannot be reasonably answered in its current form`? Really?

Comment: @SonerGönül how would you have phrased this question?

Comment: @cja This is an idiom that uses generics as an alternative to  casting. `Get` can return objects of different types, but for any particular call, the caller knows which type will be returned. *Without* generics, the only solution is having `Get` return `object` and casting the result, e.g. `entity.Name = (string)AccountName.Get(executionContext);` *With* generics, `Get` can be a generic method which returns a value of its type parameter. The type parameter has to be explicitly specified (using e.g. `<string>`) because there are no method arguments of its type from which to infer it.

Comment: @shambulator Please add an answer with the text from your two comments and I'll accept it.

Comment: @cja Thanks for the offer, but that would require getting the question reopened, and I'm sure we both have better things to do :P

Comment: @shambulator It still lets me accept answers on this question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28298/discussion-between-shambulator-and-cja)

Answer (score 1):

It's a generic type parameter, which can do several things. Read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `<string>` is defining the type that the parameter will be, this is called Generics. You can read more about Generics here ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

Comment: In this case, it has more to do with the return type than the parameter.

Comment: Why not just cast the response to a string?

Comment: It provides type safety, using generics you are ensuring that the return type is of a certain type. If you were to return an object and expect the user to cast it appropriately it increases the chances of a mistake happening.

Comment: @cja I'm in two minds on using generics in this way. Having to specify the type parameter explicitly means you don't save on any typing. Casting gives you the same type-safety benefits - you couldn't cast to `int` and try to assign to a `string` lvalue like `entity.Name`, for instance - and internally, `Get` is almost certainly casting anyway. One feature that generics *do* give you is the ability to specify constraints, e.g. that the return type implement an interface or derive from a particular base class. But so far I haven't come across a situation where this would be useful.